# Delete link_to for Comment in Nested Routes on Separate Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a situation in my app in which `comments` are nested inside the `blog` like this:

```
resources :blogs do
   resources :comments
end
```

I have a list of comments on the `users#show` page in which the user needs to be able to delete comments.  My `users_controller` is like this:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @comments = Comment.where(approved: false)
  end
```

My `comments_controller` delete method looks like this:

```
 def destroy
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
    @comment = blog.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to blog_path(@blog), notice: 'Comment has been deleted.'
  end
```

Finally, here is my delete link on the `users#show` page:

```
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
      <p><strong><%= comment.body %></strong><br />
      <em><%= comment.user.first_name %> <%= comment.user.last_name %></em></p>
      <%= link_to blog_comment_path(@blog, comment), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } do %>
        <i class="icon ion-trash-a"></i>
      <% end %>
      <%= link_to approve_comment_path(comment), method: :post do %>
        <i class="icon ion-checkmark"></i>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :blog_id=>nil, :controller=>"comments", :id=>"1"} missing required keys: [:blog_id]
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not defined `@blog` yet, so `@blog` is `nil`

You can edit that like this

`<%= link_to blog_comment_path(comment.blog, comment), method: :delete, .... %>`

Comment: Dumb mistakes.  Excellent.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to to hear that. Another trick: you can use `[comment.blog, comment]` for short instead of `blog_comment_path(comment.blog, comment)`